# Find first range not in set of ranges

Tags: c++, algorithm, bin-packing

I'm already familiar with the 1D bin packing nextFit, firstFit and bestFit + their offline algorithm variations. I mention these just for context. 
My problem is about trying to find narrowest range `(i,i+required_size)` with width >= 1 that is *not* in the set of non-overlapping ranges:

```
int required_size;
std::set<std::pair<int,int>> ranges;
std::pair<int,int> result = findNarrowestFitFor(ranges,required_size);
```

How should I try solve this?

*Explaining it to the duck: Obliviously I need to iterate the ranges and find two adjacent items that don't overlap.*

Beta asked for example code, so here is what I'm at:

```
std::vector<char> buffer;
std::map<int,int> ranges;

// Search for free space by finding narrowest range
// that is not in ranges
const char * find_free_area(size_t nbytes) {
    ptrdiff_t fit = buffer.capacity();
    auto pos = ranges.begin();
    auto itr = pos;
    if(ranges.empty()) {
        return buffer.data();
    }
    while(itr != ranges.end()) {
        // Find next hole begin
        itr = std::adjacent_find(ritr, ranges.end(),
            []( const std::pair<const int,int> & a,
                const std::pair<const int,int> & b) {
                return a.second != b.first;
        });
        if(itr == ranges.end()) {
            itr = ranges.rbegin().base();
        }
        // Get next range
        auto next = std::next(itr);
        if(next != ranges.end()) {
            auto space = next->first - itr->second;
            if(space < fit) {
                fit = space;
                pos = ranges.begin();
                std::advance(pos, itr->second);
            }
        } else if(itr->second ) {
            // todo..
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. Unless the set is ridiculously huge, there is always some range (i,i) that is not in it - a range of width 0. Or, do you need positive width? Then (i, i+1) for some i. Please clarify.

Comment: Oh, sorry the range may have maximum size e.g. [0-1024] and all inserted subranges do have positive width. So if the `findNarrowestFitFor()` would fail to fit `required_size` in [0,N] space it would error out.

Comment: I think an example would be very helpful.